# Attribute drawableTint is only used in API level 23 and higher

Tags: java, android-layout, drawable

Estou tentando colocar um ícone colorido no `EditText` mas o `Android Studio` está avisando que o atributo que colore o ícone (`android:drawableTint`) só é suportado em **`API's >= 23`**. O que eu faço para poder usar em **`API's >= 15`**?

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/mailText"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/sym_action_email"
        android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        style="@style/AppTheme.VerticalLinearLayoutSpacing" />
```